# Cloudflare DNS or Apache vhost misconfiguration?

Tags: apache, cloudflare

I have setup a website in cloudflare that pointing website3.com to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP address.

In my apache, I have existing website1.com and website2.com vhost (website 1 and 2 are using digital ocean DNS). I created a new vhost for website3.

But when I go to website3.com, It is showing the content of website1. This is probably because when I type the IP in the browser, it lead to website1.

Why is my website3 not using the vhost I have created?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the problem isn't with CloudFlare but at your server.

Assuming that name servers for website3.com point to your CloudFlare name servers and they've had time to propagate, and that website3.com is at IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and this IP is on your Digital Ocean droplet, then have you configured website3.com and the virtual host file for this domain on your droplet?

Here's one good tutorial of the steps: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Good luck!